# Pre- and post increment, no loops

Tags: java

Can someone please explain why the result for `z` equals `12`?
I've read about pre- and post increment but this right here still doesn't make sense for me.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 1, y = 2, z = 3; 
        x = x + y;
        y = y + x;
        z = z + (x++) + (++y);  
        System.out.print("x = " + x + "\ny = " + y + "\nz = " + z);
     }
}
```

Like I see it:

`x = x + y`: `x` -> `1` (post increment by one) `+ y` -> `3` (pre incremented by one), `x = 4`

`y = y + x`: `y` -> `4` (pre incremented by one again) `+ x` -> `2` (post incremented by one), `y = 6`

`z = z + (x++) + (++y)`: `z` -> `3 + x` -> `3` (post incremented by one) `+ y` -> `5` (pre incr. by one), `z` = `11`

Comment: `x = x + y` has no post-increment or pre-increment in it, so why do you think those expressions involve any post-incrementing or pre-incrementing?

Comment: What Marcin Szymczak was saying is to use your IDE's debugger to step through the code. You can set a breakpoint and examine the variables as they change to see how different operations are affecting the results.

Comment: If you're not using an IDE and trying to set it up would be too difficult, you can always rely on the `println` debugger :) :) :)

Comment: @ajb it was because when I ran the code, it gave me x = 4, y = 6.
so I just thought that that was the way to do it.
It's clear for me now that I really misunderstood the whole thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
y = x++; // This assignes x 's value to y then increment x by 1
y = ++x; // This increments x by one then assigns new x's value to y.
```

On your code

```
    int x = 1, y = 2, z = 3; 
    x = x + y;
    // x = 3
    y = y + x;
    // y = 5
    z = z + (x++) + (++y); 
    // z = 3 + 3 + 6 --> 12
```

This `z = z + (x++) + (++y);` code is equal to combination of below 3 lines of code:

```
y = y + 1; 
z = z + x + y;
x = x + 1;
```

Comment: But when I run the code, x = 4, y = 6 and then as you say z = 12

Comment: @chr911 `x` and `y` are 3 and 5 **before** the last statement (the one that assigns `z`).  The last statement sets `z` to 12, and it also causes `x` and `y` to increase by 1, so that they're 4 and 6 when you do the `print`.

Comment: Yes x is 4 at the end, As it (x++) in the last operation. X's value of 3 is used for the operation, then x is incremented by 1.

Comment: @chr911 see the last part of my answer.

Comment: @SalihErikci Thanks for your help!
Appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

See notes in code below.

The main problem with your own annotations in the question is that you're seeing pre-increment and post-increment operators where there aren't any. In `x = x + y`, for example, this is a simple assignment with no increments anywhere.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 1, y = 2, z = 3;
            // so now (x,y,z) == (1,2,3)
        x = x + y;
            // so now (x,y,z) == (3,2,3)
        y = y + x;
            // so now (x,y,z) == (3,5,3)
        z = z + (x++) + (++y);
            // here, x++ would return 3 (unincremented)
            //       ++y would return 6 (incremented)
            // so now z = 3 + 3 (unincremented x) + 6 (incremented y) == 12
            // and in the process both x and y have been incremented
            // so we have (x,y,z) == (4,6,12)
        System.out.print("x = " + x + "\ny = " + y + "\nz = " + z);
     }
}
```

Comment: @chr911 You're welcome :) Please do click the tick to mark as accepted answer if you found it useful (gets you some rep too).

Comment: @chr911 yes, sorry, too many typos! Corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make a simple analysis on the line `z = z + (x++) + (++y);` (no real code):

```
z = (previous value of z: 3) + 
    (the existing value of x (increment will take place after the plus expression evaluation): 3 (1 + 2 from previous assign statement)) +
    (the value of y after being incremented by 1: 6 (2 + 3 from previous assign statement + 1 from the increment)). =>
z = 3 + 3 + 6 =>
z = 12 //Assign 12 value to z
```